# Question in a step of constructing Out($S_6$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

In [this material](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Eeal/S6.pdf), page 5, Section **Construction of an outer automorphism of $S_6$**.

> $S_5$ acts by conjugation on six cyclic subgroups of cardinality 5 (its six Sylow 5-subgroups actually) induces homomorphism $j:S_5 \to S_6$.
>
> Write $H=j(S_5)$, $H\triangleleft S_6$ and $[S_6:H]=[S_6:S_5]=6$, $S_6$ acts by left translation on $S_6/H$ induces $F:S_6\to S_6$.
>
> Suppose $F((12))$ is a transposition, then there's a coset $xH$ s.t. $(12)xH=xH$, $x^{-1}(12)x \in H$ and is a transposition. It's proved before that $j$ preserves charity, so if $j(\sigma)=x^{-1}(12)x$, $\sigma$ is odd.

Then it claims without proof that $\sigma$ is a transposition and normalizes an Sylow $5$-subgroup $P$ (i.e. $\sigma P\sigma^{-1}=P$), and in the next step it assumes $P=\langle(12345)\rangle$ and $\sigma$ fixes $1$.

---

My question:

1.Why must $\sigma$ be a transposition?

What we know here is $\sigma$ is preimage of transposition, so it's odd.

For $\alpha=(24)(25)(23)=(2354)$, $\alpha$ is odd,
$\alpha(12345)\alpha^{-1}=(2354)(12345)(2354)^{-1}=(13524)=(12345)^2$

2.Why can we assume $P=\langle(12345)\rangle$ and $\sigma$ fixes $1$ here?

Does this assumption really not lose any generality?

Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$. Look at its cycles decompositions. There are only $5$ elements, it can't be a disjoint product of $3$ transpositions.

EDIT: $\sigma$ is of order $2$ because it's the image of a monomorphism from an element of order $2$, so its cycles decomposition must be just transpositions. It's odd so the number of transpositions must be odd.

$2$. A group of $5$ elements must be generated by an element of order $5$, and in $S_{5}$ it must be a $5$-cycle. Choosing $1,2,3,4,5$ is just naming the elements to match the cycle. You can pick whatever $\sigma$ fixed and call it $1$, then follow it along the cycle and name the subsequent elements $2,3,4,5$.